# phpmyadmin design mode is not there

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am using PHPMyadmin, i have various tables and from there i would like to design ER diagram.I have done this previously but now its not working. I have also searched online people are suggesting few things i've tried but its not working.
I have selected my database but i cannot see any Design tab, in which i can draw ER diagram Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you are confusing phpmyadmin and MySQL Designer? The latter is a standalone software app with an ER design feature suite. The former is a web app.

Comment: I am sure i am not confused between phpmyadmin and mysql - i would like to see all the tables and their relationships. Is there any way i can do this using phpmyadmin.